# Would glowing creatures be possible?

Tags: magic, creature-design, fauna

I have several creatures I either made up or based off of a mythical creature, but the major glowing creature in my world's forest is a night nymph. There are four types of nymphs in my world; Earth nymphs, tree nymphs, water nymphs and night nymphs. The they are insect like, with humanoid bodies. Only the tree nymphs and night nymphs have wings. In the day time, the tree nymphs fly about, and at night the night nymphs take their place, illuminating the forest with their purple or blue lights. These are not firefly sized, but about the size of my hand. It's the markings on their skin that glows, and there are several of them.

The other glowing creature is sort of like a dragon slug, I called them nesssies, that floats about in pools or rivers, around 5cm long. At night they light up the waters.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible for a large, insect-like creature to glow?
2. Would their glow be enough to light up a forest?
3. Would the glow of the slugs be enough to light up rivers and pools?

I'm also thinking of adding a glowing plant or something, but I'm not very keen on the idea and will only do it if absolutely necessary.

Comment: One question per post, please

Comment: Glowing organisms do exist IRL. The light isn't exceptional but based on which one you mean, you might be able to make your way around the area with the organisms around. And almost any living thing can glow when infected with glowing microorganisms. That inclides plants and even animals. Owls covered in glowing bacteria are probably the basis of several myths and legends. Since owls live in trees, they could get some of the bacteria from there. So,is your world actually not like real world that already has glowing organisms? If not, then probably you need to research IRL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several extant species that "glow" through bioluminescence. Some are small (fireflies), others are larger (various deep sea mollusks). Most constantly illuminate, to my understanding the firefly's an oddball in that regard. The output for any given organism is, at best, modest... but in a dark forest these things could certainly give enough light to see the outlines of a pool or creek on the night of a new moon (if there are enough of them).

The organism, if it is a slug or arthropod, fits quite nicely with reality, where both of these classes have members that glow.

No magic is needed, this is totally explainable in the real world.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**

There are many real creatures that glow:

[image: https://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/beetles/phengodidae06.jpg]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is certainly possible.

There are several terrestrial fauna exhibiting *bioluminescence*, which is the emission of light from an organism. It is more common to see bioluminescence in deep sea life but there are a handful of examples of insects and fungi displaying this property. I would recommend searching for the term "Glowworm", which will show you examples of beetles that can glow. These beetles are on the smaller side, but it would not be too unrealistic to have glowing organisms that are terrestrial, aquatic, or fungal to glow so bright that they light up a forest or ponds. There are examples of real-life bays that glow bright at night, Vieques in Puerto Rico for example.

Answer (score 2):

It was mentioned already that bioluminescence is a thing and that creatures exist that exhibit it naturally. But what if the concrete kind of creature you want to glow in your story does not glow in real life? Then just let it

## Escape from the lab

Basically, some tenths to hundreds (or more, if needed) years ago, creatures that were studied in labs routinely (like lab mice or rats in real life) escaped. Some were genetically engineered to unspecifically glow in the dark, because it helps the science. (I kid you not! While it makes a lot of sense to let only specific kind of cells glow, it does not always work like this, it might make sense to make, like, all cells glow in a different color or when exposed to UV.)

So, enough of fertile glowing creatures escaped, they managed to survive and to mate with their wild cousins. Now you have glowing %whatever% creatures in your forest.

By the way, the creatures that glow would also happen to be albinos, because else it is harder to perceive the glow everywhere.

This case is now taught at schools at the keyword "biohazard", and locals tell tourists scary stories about truck-sized glowing rats (or %whatever%) that can be found deep in the forest. The stories are lies, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is some debate about how brightly the genetically modified bunny glowed, or if the photo was taken under special conditions. However, biologists routinely use GFP as a biomarker and splice it into cells using it as a marker to observe the functions occurring within the cells. The GFP would normally be excited by a blue or ultraviolet light.

[image: Green Fluorescent Protein Bunny Alba]

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know: one night in 1964 the crew of an american destroyer, USS Maddox, felt threatened by what seemed to be cockpit lights of enemy ships, even opening fire against them. Reports from some of the crew say they opened fire but hit nothing and couldn't find ships by sigt or via sonar. Some biologist say the lights came from giant pyrosomes. They are colonial, bioluminescent filter feeders.

Here is a guy holding one, for reference:

[image: A giant pyrosome, resembling a jellyfish]

And here is a guy riding a colony of pyrosomes, just because he can. Remember, they glow in the dark.

[image: A guy riding a giant tube made of bioluminescent invertebrates.]

If a concentration of these colonies can trick a war ship into thinking it is facing an enemy fleet, then a collective of nymphs can light up a forest. From above it might seem there are lamps under the branches.